# One page website setup

Tags: html, css

Im starting a new website, and the homepage has a lot of div elements.
What I want to know is how to make all the div inherit the same width and height of the screen resolution instead of having a fixed width and height...

a buddy of mine recomended this piece of code, but i want to know if there's more i can do to improve my code

```
#container{
position:relative;
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
}

#top{
width:100%;
height:60px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#000;
}


.content {
position: relative;
min-width: 1024px;
min-height: 768px;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Look into an existing CSS framework like bootstrap. Unless this is purely a learning exercise, you shouldn't attempt to roll your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CSS Viewport Units: vw, vh, vmin and vmax`](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-viewport-units/)

```
div{
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh
}
```

Comment: Fairly well supported http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you. Just one question, is it supported by all browsers? Like, will i have problems with any version of IE?

Comment: @GabrielFerraz please refer to MLeFevre comment

Comment: won't happen again @Tambo thanks